# Redirecting obsolete categories and child products via 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am currently (merging) moving categories around, child products will cease to exist. 
As we have quite a few products it makes sense to redirect all products under the parent category.

**Example URL:**

```
http://www.domain.com/chandeliers/modern-chandeliers/*
```

(Where '*' = Child products/urls)

**Redirect URL:**

```
http://www.domain.com/chandeliers/
```

**Currently Displayed as:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^chandeliers\/modern-chandeliers\/$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/chandeliers\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The code I'm using doesn't redirect child products, only parent categories.

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^chandeliers/modern-chandeliers/ http://www.domain.com/chandeliers/ [R=301,L]
```

The `$` was removed since we only want to match up to `modern-chandeliers/`. Also removed the quotes and unneeded escaping. You also don't need the `RewriteCond`, as it doesn't affect anything. Note that this makes it so if someone goes to `http://www.domain.com/chandeliers/modern-chandeliers/a-product-uri`, they get redirected to `http://www.domain.com/chandeliers/`, regardless of anything after the `modern-chandeliers/`. If you want to also include everything after `modern-chandeliers/`, your rule needs to look lke this:

```
RewriteRule ^chandeliers/modern-chandeliers/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/chandeliers/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This makes it so when someone requests `http://www.domain.com/chandeliers/modern-chandeliers/a-product-uri`, they get redirected to `http://www.domain.com/chandeliers/a-product-uri`.

Alternatively, you could ditch mod_rewrite and use mod_alias for that:

```
Redirect 301 /chandeliers/modern-chandeliers /chandeliers
```

Comment: Thank you Jon Lin, - The code provided worked great!
For those using CS-Cart and moving categories: A) If you are moving a product into another category - Use Jon's solution. B) If you are moving all products from multiple categories into one category (combining) use the following code:    RewriteRule ^category1/category2/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/newcategory/ [R=301,L]